# Which standards are SS7 MAP Tags defined in?

Tags: dictionary, tags, ss7

Can anyone give me information on which standard contains MAP Tags - sm-RP-UI?

```
  04 1a - sm-RP-UI
  24 - TP-RP/UDHI/SRI/MMS/MTI
  0b  - length
  91 26 18 18 55 32 f7 - TP-Originating-Address
  00 - TP-PID
  00 - TP-DCS
  90 40 02 91 61 42 82 - TP-Service-Centre-Time-Stamp
  07 - TP-User-Data-Length: (7) depends on Data-Coding-Scheme
  ca f0 3a 2c a7 87 01 - TP-User-Data
```

The details are needed for coding and I'd like to know which standard they are in. I have been looking in `GSM 29.002`, `GSM 23.040`, and `GSM 24.011` and I haven't found them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SMTL PDUs are defined in [3GPP TS 23.040 - Technical realization of the Short Message Service (SMS)](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/23040.htm)

More specifically:

```
04 1a
```

This is ASN.1 tag a length (OCTET STRING). Since you say this is sm-RP-UI
it would be the SignalInfo ASN.1 type defined in 3GPP TS 29.002
used with labels sm-RP-UI on different MAP operations.

```
24
```

First thing to look here are the last two bits (TP-Message-Type-Indicator: 9.2.3.1 of 23.040)
Since you have H'24 -> B'00100100. This is an SMS-DELIVER (SC to MS)

SMS-DELIVER (9.2.2.1) contains

- TP-Message-Type-Indicator (TP-MTI on 9.2.3.1) (bit 0-1 --> 00)
- TP-More-Messages-To-Send (TP-MMS on 9.2.3.2)  (bit 2 --> 1: "No more messages are waiting for the MS in this SC
- TP-Status-Report-Indication (TP-SRI on 9.2.3.4) (bit 5 --> 1: "A status report shall be returned to the SME")
- TP-User-Data_Header-Indicator (TP-UDHI on 9.2.3.23) (bit 6 -> 0: "The TP-UD field contains only the short message")
- TP-Reply-Path (TP-RP on 9.2.3.17) (bit 7 -> 0: "Not set")

> 0b 91 26 18 18 55 32 f7

- TP-Originating-Address (TP-OA 9.2.3.7 - Address fields in 9.1.2.5) that works:
  ** Address-Length: H'B = D'11 (not this is in semi-octets)
  ** Type-of-Address: H'91=B'10010001 with Type-of-Nuymber (B'001: International number) and Numbering-Plan (B'0001: ISDN/E.164)
  ** Address-Value: BCD: 62818155327 (F is filler)

> 00

- TP-Protocol-Identifier (TP-PID 9.2.3.9)

> 00

- TP-Data-Coding-Scheme (TP-DCS 9.2.3.10)

> 90 40 02 91 61 42 82

- TP-Service-Centre-Time-Stamp (TP-SCTS 9.2.3.11) 2009/04/20 19:16:24

> 07

- TP-User-Data-Length (TP-UDL 9.2.3.16)

> ca f0 3a 2c a7 87 01
>   * TP-User-Data (TP-UD 9.2.3.24)